# Soundcloud API error 401 when i use a token later than just after i get it

Tags: soundcloud

I would like to understand why i get "The requested URL responded with HTTP code 401." when i try to put a description whith an access token.

The weird think is it works fine when i do that just after getting the access_token (session) from the user, but when i store the token, and try to launch the same code later, it fail !

Apparantly, there is a problem with the token, because i can access the soundcloud description without token, but if i use this method: $soundcloud->setAccessToken($token); before getting the tracks datas, i can't access them anymore...

Here is the code:

```
require_once 'soundcloud/Soundcloud.php';
$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud(SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID, SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_SECRET, SOUNDCLOUD_REDIRECT_URI);
$soundcloud->setAccessToken($session_token);
try
{
    $track = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks/'.$media_id), true);
}
catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e)
{
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
try
{
    $response = json_decode($soundcloud->put(
                                     'tracks/'.$media_id,
                                              'test',
                                               array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml'))), true);
}
catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e)
{
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

This code works when i just get the token but fail if i launch it a few days later...

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is $session_token coming from in this example? Depending on how you generated the access token, one of two things are happening:

1. You are not sending the correct access token.
2. The access token you are sending has expired.

If it's 2, you should have gotten a refresh token when the user authorizes your app. The PHP SoundCloud SDK has a accessTokenRefresh() method that you can use in this scenario.

Comment: Hello,

I saw on the doc you can now ask for a non expiring token and it solved the problem.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

You need a non-expiring token.

When authorizing, the param `scope` defaults to `"*"`.

Specify the scope and retrieve the token like this:

```
$soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl(array('scope'=>'non-expiring'))
```

See: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connect

(Quite old question, but just ran into this myself. When the token is expired you don't get feedback from the API other then the 401 error, leaving you in the dark.)